# Search with the command Like%

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following data

```
ORING10,0X2,0NBR70
ORING100,0X2,0NBR70
ORING20,0X2,5FKM75
ORING222,0X3,78VMQ70
ORING170,0X2,65NBR70
```

etc.

How do I extract the ORINGS that are greater or equal to 100,0 and less than 200,0?

When I do ORING1%%, I get nothing
When I do ORING1%, I get 10's and 100's

Thank you for your assistance.

RB

Comment: Really - your data is stored comma separated in a string? Please add your table definition.

Comment: `WHERE SUBSTRING(column FROM 6) + 0 BETWEEN 100 AND 200`.

Comment: These are stocknumbers we did not want to just work with numbers because each size could have various materials and hardness NBR, FKM and VMQ is the material and the number thereafter 70 and 75 is the material hardness (shore or durometer)

Answer (score 0):

One option would be determining the first occurences of the comma character and the the substring `ORING`, and starting to extract the part from length of `ORING` added to that first occurence :

```
SELECT str AS orings
  FROM t
 WHERE SUBSTR(str,INSTR(str,'ORING')+LENGTH('ORING'),
                  INSTR(str,',')-INSTR(str,'ORING')-LENGTH('ORING')) 
 BETWEEN 100 and 199
```

where the pattern of the whole data in the table is assumed to be `ORING[INT],....`

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ccc3b3cd36b4c839a389c2699f016ba2)</kbd>